# how to redirect user to default page on session time out in asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session-state, session-timeout

i just want to redirect user to Home Page(Default.aspx) when session has been expired in asp.net 3.5.
i just do it with web user control but steel it's not work perfectly. so i just want to do it with web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/SignIn.aspx" protection="All" timeout="2880" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

Is this technique works in .net 3.5 framework application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using **form authentication** then you don't have to write any custom code. For session timeout settings are provided by Framework itself. Just change the configuration file as mentioned below :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"
        loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"
        slidingExpiration="true"
        timeout="60" />
</authentication>
```

Above configuration will redirect user to the login page when session expires.

Comment: can i set both default and login url same.

Answer (score 5):

You can check for session on page_init as show below

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckSession();
}

private void CheckSession()
{
   if (Session["SessionID"] == null || !System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**For No Master Page:**

you may try this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx", false);
    }
}
```

Use this logic in every webpage

**If Master Page is Used:**

Use the above logic in your masterpage.cs file

**Using Web.Config:**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/SignIn.aspx" protection="All" timeout="2880" path="/" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
<deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: Why in every webpage when there are masterpages for asp.net webforms? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX

Answer (score 3):

I would use a masterpage for all webforms except the `SignIn.aspx` and have this in the masterpages init method:

```
if((System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User == null) || !System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    Response.Redirect("SignIn.aspx");
```

[MSDN article about forms authentication.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)