# Session Timeout Expired

Tags: c#

Right now i am using the below code in web.config file to maintain session timeout.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms 
        loginUrl="index.aspx" 
        name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" 
        timeout="1"
        protection="All" 
        slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication> 
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="1"/>
```

This code fine.it works..

But the problem is,if session timeout expires(tat is after 1 minute) it will not automatically redirect to my loginurl-"index.aspx" i need to suppose to click any of the button in my web page then only it redirects to loginurl.

i need to redirect my page automatically to loginurl without any click or mouseover(), once session expired .

Thanks in advance.
Hope you help!

Comment: Use an async task?

Comment: Where it gets redirected currently?

Comment: @Anand It currently redirected to login page (index.aspx) when i click.

Comment: @Gino How can i use async. If possible please explain clearly.Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803858/how-to-redirect-user-to-default-page-on-session-time-out-in-asp-net-3-5

Comment: @Anand its not working for me and my framework is 4.5

Comment: @Anand i need to refresh my webpage once session expire then only it is possible right...?